# XML to JSON having an option for arrays with one element

Tags: java, xml, json, jackson

I use org.json to convert XML into JSON at a Java code:

```
JSONObject jSONObject = org.json.XML.toJSONObject(StringXML);
```

The problem with org.json libs are they don't accept array with one element, so I'm having trouble to read the JSON with jQuery's datatable. (No bracket around the element)

So, I wanted to switch to Jackson since I found out the it has an option for it:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
```

But, when I imported the latest libs (core: 2.2.3, dataformat-xml: 2.2.0), DeserializationFeature class is not available.

Is there any way to convert XML string into JSON having an option for the arrays with one element?

Answer (score 0):

I have used staxon API to convert from XML to JSON.

```
import de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLConfig;
import de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLConfigBuilder;
import de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLInputFactory;

InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileIn); // XML file input
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileOut); // JSON output file 

JsonXMLConfig config = new JsonXMLConfigBuilder().multiplePI(false).build();
XMLEventReader reader = new JsonXMLInputFactory(config)
                            .createXMLEventReader(input);
XMLEventWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance()
                            .createXMLEventWriter(output);
```

Download API from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadstaxon10jar.htm).

You can try this out.

Comment: Is it possible to input and output String instead of FileInputStream and FileOutputStream? I couldn't find it at the API.

Comment: Yes, use `StringReader` and `StringWriter`